# Group By not working in DBPedia

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am working in [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/snorql). I am having a problem when using group by in Sparql.

I have this code:

```
SELECT ?res ?titulo
        WHERE {
            ?res rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/JaguaresDeChiapasFootballers> .
            ?res rdfs:label ?titulo .
        }       
GROUP BY (?res)
LIMIT 15
```

I want to return a list of all in this type. But I only want to return one for each URI, I put the group by and it doesn’t work and I really don’t know why?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original query isn't legal SPARQL.  If you paste it into the SPARQL query validator at [sparql.org](http://sparql.org/validate/query), you'll get the following message:

> Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?titulo

If you **group by** ?res, then you can't select the non-group variable ?titulo.  If you just want one ?titulo value per ?res, then you can use …

```
select ?res (sample(?titulo) as ?title)
…
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fres%20%28sample%28%3Ftitulo%29%20as%20%3Ftitle%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fres%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FJaguaresDeChiapasFootballers%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fres%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ftitulo%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fres%0D%0ALIMIT%2015&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you want a list of the titles, then you can use **group_concat** to concatenate the titles:

```
select ?res (group_concat(?titulo;separator=', ') as ?title)
…
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%3Fres%20%28group_concat%28%3Ftitulo%3Bseparator%3D%27%2C%20%27%29%20as%20%3Ftitle%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fres%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FJaguaresDeChiapasFootballers%3E%20.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fres%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ftitulo%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fres%0D%0ALIMIT%2015&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: A different approach is to ORDER BY ?res so that related items are adjacent in the results stream, then process them knowing that fact.